# push notification without mobile app

Tags: push-notification

I have a website. Currently I have been sending sms during some transactions as notification.

I want to use push notification instead of sms. But I don't have any mobile app.

How can I send push notifications without a app. Are there any way to do it?

Comment: push notification to users browsing your Web site?

Comment: No, to specific people

Comment: logically, i think it can only be possible if those users are online (to your server).

Comment: Is there any commonly app  that users install it then I send push to the app?

Comment: you can't send notification to those apps without proper authentication!

Comment: Apple provides documentation on how to do this with Safari: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Spontit](https://spontit.com) enables you to send push notifications to all devices - desktop, iOS, Android, etc. You can do so for free and without your own app.

You can check out their API [here](https://api.spontit.com).

Comment: spontit is now dead

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this without developing an app for each platform (Android/iOS). You could also get away with something like a browser plugin. Essentially what your asking for is what your doing, an SMS or an Email. That is as close as you can get w/o an app. You can make a notification system on a website, but there is no way to push it to the user when they are not on your site w/o them downloading something like a plugin. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with https://pushed.co
they allow users to download their app and you push to the users with their app without needing to have your own mobile app